# Building a Twitter Composer Modal with URL Rewriting

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter, url-shortener

I've built my own Twitter app in PHP with the front end using Twitter Bootstrap as the framework.

I want to build a composer window, so that my app can post a tweet (or a reply). It would need to integrate with bit.ly (and potentially other URL shorteners). Rather than reinvent the wheel, is there something I can use that preferably uses jQuery?

Ideally it would...

1. Have a character counter that counts down from 140 and gives a
   negative number when you go over 140 chars. Ideally it would refuse
   to send if there are more than 140 chars.
2. Rewrite URLS on the fly (Ajax) using bit.ly or other URL shorteners
   and reduce the character account accordingly once shortened. The 
   importance of using bit.ly would be to use custom URL shorteners
3. Style screen names and hashtags on the fly.

I've searched GitHub and can't seem to find anything. I've also checked out [twitter-text-js](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js/) from Twitter, but although it helps with some of what I want to do, the documentation is nonsensical and overly complex and it doesn't integrate with bitly.

There are plenty of social media apps that have the functionality I am looking for, but there doesn't seem to be any example code that is open source and uses PHP/jQuery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js is Twitter's JavaScript library for handling text counters, detection of URLs/usernames/hashtags, etc. You may find it extremely useful.

**edit:** `twttr.txt.isInvalidTweet` and `twttr.txt.getTweetLength` are likely what you want.

A note: URL shortening doesn't change the length of a tweet. All URLs take up a consistent number of characters in a Twitter post, because Twitter passes all URLs through their `t.co` shortener. In fact, `http://bit.ly` doesn't take up 13 characters, it takes up **22** for this reason.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it could be useful in part. The documentation isn't very clear and I've tried to look for actual examples of use and it seems I can't find any! Unfortunately twitter-text-js partly uses ruby it seams. I'm really looking for something that can rewrite URLs on the fly using bit.ly

Comment: Yeah, docs aren't clear, but it's all in there and you shouldn't need ruby for it.

Comment: That looks like a really good option, however when reviewing the test files, it may be a bit of learning curve. The OP seemed to suggest a jquery implementation (this does use that but..) which of course means the OP is probably a( more familiar with jquery, and most importantly  could also assume b) is looking for a more fluid, ease of use and implemented resource. For 100 reputation, seems like more than one option could be presented. Of course, if more than one option simply does not exist, this is understandable. This is a great resource, but you may need to do a lot of testing work.

Comment: @Runthis The main issue with a jQuery implementation is that it's not necessarily going to exactly follow Twitter's implementation. Best to use the one that's going to behave **exactly** like Twitter's at-times odd configuration.

Comment: Agreed. My only concern is the process of learning the new tool and the benefits or disadvantages that may come with it. +1

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you guys. I've spent ages with twitter-text and it really needs to have some examples. It's not just a steep learning curve! It does have a great way of converting screen names, hashtags and links into hyperlinks but that's the easy bit. It doesn't seem to have the character counter (although this would be easy to code) but more importantly it doesn't seem to offer bitly url shortening on the fly. I'm really surprised there isn't something that exists.

Comment: @iagdotme First, yes, it has the character counter. Look at `twttr.txt.isInvalidTweet` and `twttr.txt.getTweetLength`. Second, automatic `bit.ly` shortening is pointless, as Twitter passes URLs through its own shortener, and their character limits (including in this JS lib) take that into account automatically.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for your reply. Not had the chance to look further at this due to other projects but will come back to it. Actually automatic `bit.ly` shortening isn't pointless. `bit.ly` offers custom url shorteners (such as my own, `to.iag.me`) and analytics.

Comment: @iagdotme Sorry, I meant pointless for the purposes of character limits.